# Why does my large multi-project gradle build start up slowly?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am on a team that has a large multi-project build (~350 modules) and we have noticed that doing an individual build (-a) still takes a large amount of time.  When building the entire set of things the overhead isn't so bad, but when we do something like:

```
cd my/individual/project
gradle -a --configure-on-demand --daemon build
```

that it still takes 30-40 seconds just in the configuration phase (before it starts building anything, which we measure using the --dry-run option)

We have approximately 10 custom tasks and we **are** setting the inputs and outputs for those tasks but we still see this inordinately long configuration time.  We are using gradle 1.10

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to say from a distance. A common mistake is to do work in the configuration phase that should be done in the execution phase. Here is an example:

```
task myTask {
    copy {
        from ...
        to ...
    }
}
```

Here, the `project.copy` method will be called (and therefore copying will take place) every single time the task is *configured*, which is for every single build invocation - no matter which tasks are run! To fix this, you'd move the work into a *task action*:

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from ...
            into ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or even better, use a predefined task type:

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
    from ...
    into ...
}
```

Some steps you can take to find the cause(s) for performance problems:

- Review the build
- Run with `--info`, `--debug`, or `--profile`
- Profile the build with a Java profiler

PS: Specifying inputs and outputs doesn't shorten configuration time (but likely execution time).

Comment: It is true that we had this problem in the early stages of development.  However we believe we have removed things that did too much during configuration.  We are currently looking at timings with a java profiler and are seeing a lot of overhead for script compilation and especially classloading

Comment: That's strange. Compiled scripts are cached, and class loading shouldn't be a major problem. If you have `buildscript {}` blocks in child projects or under `allprojects/subprojects {}`, try to replace them with a single, top-level `buildscript` block in the root build script. Make sure you don't do anything time-consuming in `allprojects/subprojects`, and make sure the build (i.e. daemon process) has enough heap and permgen space (configurable in `gradle.properties`, see Gradle user guide). Without reviewing the build myself, that's about all I can say.

Comment: Upvoted answer just for your comment. Removing buildscript{} blocks from child projects brought my configuration time down from ~15(very annoying) to ~2s(extremely tolerable).